# Xcode 4 breaks localized "Release" build!

Tags: xcode, localization, app-store

I've localized my app using Xcode 4 and built it. In Debug mode it ran just fine... However, when I downloaded the update from the App Store, it ran in English. When I changed my device to the localized localized language, it crashed!

Then, I tried building in "Release" mode directly to my device. Xcode 4 says it can't attach to the PID...

I've tried both GCC and  LLVM. The app refuses to run with the Xcode 4's "Release" build mode (or the duplicate "App Store" build).

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to fix this is to manually copy your MainWindow.xib file into your other lproj folders. Xcode 4 doesn't seem to create the files for you, it just crashes.